# LiveData not working until user performs some action

Tags: android, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

My `LiveData` is not working.

`ViewModel`:

```
 private var _email = MutableLiveData<String>()

 fun setEmail(){
    _email.postValue("azizjon@bla.mn")
 }

 fun getEmail(): LiveData<String>{
     return _email
 }
```

`Fragment`'s `onViewCreated` method
:

```
 mViewModel.getEmail().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
    tvEmail.text = it
 })

 mViewModel.setEmail() //Trying to post data to my LiveData.
```

The above code is not working as `tvEmail` is not chaning.

However, if I trust a button for posting data to LiveData like this,  it is working:

```
 //Inside fragment again
 button.setOnClickListener {
     mViewModel.setEmail()
 }
```

When user clicks button, text in `tvEmail` is changing. If user does not click, nothing is happening.  What am I missing here?

**Edit:**

I have just tested the code with `Activity`. Surprisingly, for `Activity`s it is working but not for `Fragment`s.

Comment: where did you placed mViewModel.setEmail()  in application. Is this code written inside oncreate() function?

Comment: @DivakarMurugesh It is inside `Fragment`'s `onViewCreated` method

Comment: where did you initialize view model varialble?

Comment: @DivakarMurugesh in the parent `Fragment` class' `onViewCreated` method.

Answer (score 1):

@Azizjon Kholmatov - Best practice you can write your code inside the **"onActivityCreated"** function

please refer this. If you still having the problem let me know in comments section. I am happy to help. :)

```
class MainFragment : Fragment() {

    companion object {
        fun newInstance() = MainFragment()
    }

    private lateinit var viewModel: MainViewModel

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_fragment, container, false)
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainViewModel::class.java)

        viewModel.getEmail().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            tvEmail.text = it
        })

        viewModel.setEmail("first@email.com")

        button.setOnClickListener {
            viewModel.setEmail("clicked@email.com")
        }
    }
}
```

And ViewModel class as follows

```
class MainViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private var _email = MutableLiveData<String>()

    fun setEmail(email: String = "example@email.com") {
        _email.postValue(email)
    }

    fun getEmail(): LiveData<String> {
        return _email
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. Looks like there was another issue in my code. I am trying to investigate more.